# MacOS Catalinaでシリアルポートが見えない

Tags: macos, spresense, arduino

お世話になります。
Mac OS 10.15.5 Catalinaにバージョンアップしてから
SPRESENSE 2.01 ArduinoIDE版 1.8.13
という環境でUSB-シリアルポートが見れなくなってしまいました。

CP210x USB to UART Bridge VCP Driversをインストールし直してもNG
インストール時の「セキュリティ設定　開発元のブロックを解除」してもNG
下記の方法でドライバーをリロードしてもNG

- [cp210x USB to UART Bridge VCP Driver をmacで認識させる方法](https://www.shangtian.tokyo/entry/2018/09/13/224853)
- [Mac OS X 10.10.5(Yosemite)にUSB - UART ブリッジ VCP ドライバをインストール - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Mizmiz1229Xx/items/3032228e594fa826c68a)

インストールもエラー無く終了するし
コマンドでドライバーをロードしてもエラーメッセージ無し
しかし、ArduinoIDEにはシリアルポートが表示されないという・・・
なにか情報ヒントをいただければありがたく。

Answer (score 1):

私もmacOSのバージョンをアップデートした後、最新ドライバがインストールできない症状に悩まされましたが、以前インストールした古いドライバがインストールできたのでそれでシリアルポートが開けるようになりました。

ちょっとこれでは気持ち悪いので、私の場合はOS自身を再インストールして、最新ドライバをインストールしました。OSの再インストール後は問題なくドライバのインストールができました。
古いドライバをインストールした後にOSのアップデートをすると、新しいドライバがインストールできないのでしょうか、、、。